# Arguments and return type not inferred properly in function typed as union

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I'm defining a Function union type `GetThing` which I'm then using for the `getThing` function.

However when I check the type of either `name` or `thing`, they're both any. I would expect `name` to be `string` and `thing` to be `Thing1 | Thing2`

Additionally I would expect the return type of the `getThing` function to depend on the type of the `thing` argument, which should be inferred by that `switch`, but we're not even getting that far.

```
interface Thing1 {
    type: "thing1";
}

interface Thing2 {
    type: "thing2";
}


type GetThing1 = (name: string, thing: Thing1) => string;
type GetThing2 = (name: string, thing: Thing2) => boolean;
type GetThing = GetThing1 | GetThing2;

const getThing: GetThing = (name, thing) => {
   switch (thing.type) {
      case "thing1": {
          return "thingy";
      }
      case "thing2": {
          return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Is this a bug in Typescript, is this just too many layers of inference deep for Typescript to handle, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of Typescript.

(For your initial question, they're both `any` because it can't identify that function as being of type GetThing1 or GetThing2. But, you'd still have an issue even if you defined them manually to be `(name: string, thing: Thing1 | Thing2)`).

I simplified your code a little, to:

```
type Foo = (v: number) => string;
type Bar = (v: string) => boolean;
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

const fooBar: FooBar = (v: number | string) => {

   switch (typeof v) {
      case "number": {
          return "thingy";
      }
      case "string": {
          return true;
      }
   }
}

console.log(fooBar('Bob'));
```

Which may be a little clearer.

Your snippet doesn't type the inputs to getThing, but they're implied to be:

`(name: string, thing: Thing1|Thing2)`

So (using the above example for simplicity), `FooBar` is defined to be either a `Foo`, or a `Bar`. That is, either a `(number)=>string`, or a `(string)=>bool`.

From Typescript's pedantic point of view, `(number|string) => string | bool` is just not the same as either of those - it doesn't care that you've written it correctly and the types would work out.

I believe the core issue in [this feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) is the same, with a couple work-arounds given [further down](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-483995795). It's apparently not a trivial thing for Typescript to handle, conceptually.

I'd recommend one of the following:

```
type Foo = (v: number) => string;
type Bar = (v: string) => boolean;
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

let foo: Foo = (v: number) => {
    return "heyo";
}
let bar: Bar = (v: string) => {
    return true;
}

type FooBarDiscriminator = (v: number | string) => string | boolean;
const fooBar1: FooBarDiscriminator = (v: number | string) => {
    switch (typeof v) {
        case "number": {
            return foo(v);
        }
        case "string": {
            return bar(v);
        }
    }
}

function fooBar2(v: number | string) {
    switch (typeof v) {
        case "number": {
            return foo(v);
        }
        case "string": {
            return bar(v);
        }
    }
}

console.log(fooBar1(0));
console.log(fooBar1('Bob'));
console.log(fooBar2(0));
console.log(fooBar2('Bob'));
```